# remove 3/min-limit of UFW logging (the clean way)?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, syslog, ufw

since I'm not satisfied with th iptables ansible module (not stateful) I'm trying my way with UFW.

Problem is, that UFW limits logging to 3/min which might be enough for nonentusiasts.

so my solution (not working) was:
copy the modified logging section to */etc/ufw/after.rules* (before `commit`):

```
-A ufw-after-logging-input -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
```

disabling UFW logging (so logging lines from *user.rules* are removed) and reloading the rules.

It seems UFW takes the "no logging" serious and does no logging at all.

Is there a permanent and clean* solution? (not something like replacing *user.rules* after every reload via separate script or anything dirty like that.)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'high' is the lowest [log level](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ufw.8.html#logging) without rate limiting.

```
# Ansible task
- name: Set logging to not rate limit
  ufw:
    logging: high
```

There is not really a way to exclude the additional logging of all packets. Heed the warning:

> Loglevels  above  medium  generate  a  lot of logging output, and may quickly fill up your disk.

Comment: that would be 2nd choice, cause this would log way more than I need. also i prefer to have some special prefixes for some cases (which wouldn't be a problem using iptables only)

Comment: That does not appear to be a distinction provided by "Uncomplicated Firewall". Likely you will need to enhance ufw or use a different firewall script.

Comment: yes, I give up on ufw and use pure iptables again (iptables_raw ansible module, for being idempotent)